# Apply filter on Dimension or Metric in Google Analytics API using C# library

Tags: c#, asp.net, filter, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have been able to authenticate my app on google analytics and display some data around unique page views. Now I want to get the page views based on Traffic source but I'm not quite sure how to get the filters on the dimensions. I have written my code in c# and can't get my head around examples in other languages I've seen. i have used the api Query Explorer and got the right expressions and results. My difficulty is how to translate that into my code. My code is below

```
    var filepath = Server.MapPath("~/jsonfile");  // path to the json file for the Service account
        GoogleCredential credentials;
        using (var stream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string[] scopes = { AnalyticsReportingService.Scope.AnalyticsReadonly };
            var googleCredential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream);
            credentials = googleCredential.CreateScoped(scopes);
        }

        var reportingService = new AnalyticsReportingService(
        new BaseClientService.Initializer
        {
        HttpClientInitializer = credentials
        });


        var dateRange = new DateRange
        {
            StartDate = "2016-10-28",
            EndDate = "2016-12-20"
        };

        var sessions = new Metric
        {
            Expression = "ga:uniquePageviews", 
            Alias = "Sessions"
        };


        var social = new Dimension { Name = "ga:socialNetwork" };



        var reportRequest = new ReportRequest
        {
            DateRanges = new List<DateRange> { dateRange },
            Dimensions = new List<Dimension> { social },
            Metrics = new List<Metric> { sessions },
            ViewId = "myviewid" 
        };

        var getReportsRequest = new GetReportsRequest
        {
            ReportRequests = new List<ReportRequest> { reportRequest }
        };

        var batchRequest = reportingService.Reports.BatchGet(getReportsRequest);
        var response = batchRequest.Execute();
        foreach (var x in response.Reports.FirstOrDefault().Data.Rows)
        {
            Response.Write(string.Join(", ", x.Dimensions) + "   " + string.Join(", ", x.Metrics.First().Values));
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should create a `DimensionFilterClauses` and pass it to the `ReportRequest` as follows:

```
//Create the Dimension Filter
var dimensionFilter = new DimensionFilter();
dimensionFilter.DimensionName = "ga:socialNetwork";
dimensionFilter.Expressions = new List<string> { "someValue" };
var dimensionFilterClause = new DimensionFilterClause();
dimensionFilterClause.Filters = new List<DimensionFilter> { dimensionFilter };
```

Then modify your `ReportRequest`:

```
var reportRequest = new ReportRequest
{
    DateRanges = new List<DateRange> { dateRange },
    Dimensions = new List<Dimension> { social },
    Metrics = new List<Metric> { sessions },
    ViewId = "myviewid",
    DimensionFilterClauses = new List<DimensionFilterClause> { dimensionFilterClause }
};
```

**P.S:**
Furthermore, if you need to filter Metric instead of Dimension, you would need to create a `MetricFilterClauses` as follows and then pass it to `MetricFilterClauses` in your `ReportRequest`:

```
//Create the Metric Filter
var metricFilter = new MetricFilter();
metricFilter.MetricName = "someMetric";
metricFilter.ComparisonValue = "someValue";
var metricFilterClause = new MetricFilterClause();
metricFilterClause.Filters = new List<MetricFilter> { metricFilter };
```